# How to add a border around the entire DataGrid column header?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I've customized the `DataGrid` a lot, but surprisingly I'm unable to add a border around the entire header area without it breaking.

So this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: Pretty simple right?]

The following control is responsible for displaying the header area: `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`.

I added a border around it, and as you can see from the screenshot above, it does work, but the problems begin only when the **grid is empty!** (this means that also the empty row needs to be removed, which can be done by setting `CanUserAddRows="False"`).

So far, here's my style:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                    Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
    </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>
</Border>
```

All I did was wrap it with a border, but now when I apply filtering so that the grid is empty, the header disappears to the right and the application slows down to a crawl.

Demonstration:

[image: demonstration]

If I remove the border, everything works as expected. It seems like the DataGrid is expecting a very specific tree structure, otherwise it just explodes.

I tried changing the template of the `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`, but also that expects a very specific structure which looks like this:

```
<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
        <Grid>
            <DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader"
                                  IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Template>
```

If I give the `DataGridColumnHeader` a `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness`, it doesn't look right, and if I add my own border control anywhere, the same problem arises.

The `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` actually has `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` properties, but they have no effect at all.

One workaround I found was to set `Grid.Column` to `0` so that it goes in place of the row headers column header, then just set `HeadersVisibility="Column"` on the `DataGrid` so it doesn't look broken, and the problem disappears. Unfortunately I need the row headers, so this is an unacceptable solution.

Default style for DataGrid can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates), or just right-click it in Visual Studio and go to Edit Template, then Edit a Copy, which is what I did.

There must be an easy way to accomplish this that I'm probably just not seeing right now...

Comment: The border should be added to the template of `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`. [It will work just fine](https://imgur.com/SuXtz53).

Comment: @jsanalytics It works because you have an empty row, try removing it by setting `CanUserAddRows="False"` and see what happens.

Comment: @ShahinDohan Would you then post relevant code? See also [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In that case you'll need to reach  `DataGridHeaderBorder` inside `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`. [See here](https://imgur.com/H4G2kgl).

Comment: I meant to say `DataGridHeaderBorder` inside `DataGridColumnHeader` inside `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`.

Comment: @jsanalytics I can't believe I missed that while debugging! It works now. Could you post your code as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer? Thank you!

Comment: Nay... i want to see what YOU did...:O) Post your solution !

Comment: @jsanalytics Will do so as soon as I have the time, little busy with another project at the moment. If you're still sure you don't want the points... :)

Comment: It's a 15-minute task...:O) POST IT !

Comment: @jsanalytics More than 15 minutes for us non experts ;) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but that is not a good "solution". Now you have a template with a fixed color, which means you can't reuse it. You should use `TemplateBinding` instead and delegate the actual color assignment to the corresponding style.  Having your custom controls respect themes is actually a good thing, so removing `DataGridHeaderBorder ain't good either. "Fill our requirements" is not good enough.

Comment: @jsanalytics I know that, I just left the fixed values here because it's example code. I don't care about `DataGridHeaderBorder` because I know for a fact that we will never be using any other themes in our applications. I've learned a hard lesson trying to over engineer my code, so I'm going to trust our business requirements and do what they actually ask me to do :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so I just returned to tackle this problem after @jsanalytics pointed out the existence `DataGridHeaderBorder`, and by analyzing the default tree structure more deeply, with a little bit of trial and error, I managed to get the job done.

I did not want the `DataGridHeaderBorder` though, which is part of the Windows themes, but replaced it with a regular border.

My implementation:

```
<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
   Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
   <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Template>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
           <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
               <ItemsPresenter />
               <DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                   <DataGridColumnHeader.Template>
                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                           <Grid>
                               <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
                                   <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                                     SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                               </Border>
                               <!--Uncomment if you need these resizing grippers-->
                               <!--<Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                               <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />-->
                           </Grid>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                   </DataGridColumnHeader.Template>
               </DataGridColumnHeader>
           </Grid>
       </ControlTemplate>
   </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Template>
</DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>
```

You'll probably need to tweak it for your own needs, but this fills our requirements :-)